# How can know which is library's bytecode?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, solc

When I compile solidity file that has more then two contracts, Solc gives me some binaries.

That binaries include bytecode of library.

How can I know which one is library's bytecode if I don't have any information about contracts such as contract's name?

[image]

like this image(blue box is just file path)

if i only have those bytecodes, how can I know which is library? (In this picture Ownable is Library)
plus, if I want to deploy this contracts, do I have to deploy all of them?

Comment: The name of each binary file is the name of the contract or library.

Comment: Um...I know that. But what I am curious about is how to know if there are only binary without a name.

Comment: Please share how exactly you are getting "only binary without a name".

Comment: I added the content to the text, could you take a look at it?

Comment: Are you joking? The contract name appears right above the binary!

Comment: oh I don't want to know the name of the contract, but I'm wondering if I can find out if it's a library or not by looking at the binary.